# How to make React Styled Component Responsive

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I got this very beautiful and sleek sign-in/sign-up form with React Styled Component from Youtube. However, it is not responsive. I have tried using my inspector tool to manipulate every single css detail but it just doesn't work.

Should I give up on using the sleek form/ It's the best I've seen so far.

This is the Styled Component.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
width: 678px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
`;

export const SignUpContainer = styled.div`
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 left: 0;
 width: 50%;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 ${props => props.signinIn !== true ? `
   transform: translateX(100%);
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 5;
 ` 
 : null}
`;


export const SignInContainer = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
z-index: 2;
${props => (props.signinIn !== true ? `transform: translateX(100%);` : null)}
`;

export const Form = styled.form`
background-color: #ffffff;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 0 50px;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
`;

export const Title = styled.h1`
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
`;

export const Input = styled.input`
background-color: #eee;
border: none;
padding: 12px 15px;
margin: 8px 0;
width: 100%;
`;


export const Button = styled.button`
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #ff4b2b;
   background-color: #ff4b2b;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 12px 45px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
   &:active{
       transform: scale(0.95);
   }
   &:focus {
       outline: none;
   }
`;
export const GhostButton = styled(Button)`
background-color: transparent;
border-color: #ffffff;
`;

export const Anchor = styled.a`
color: #333;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 15px 0;
`;
export const OverlayContainer = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
z-index: 100;
${props =>
 props.signinIn !== true ? `transform: translateX(-100%);` : null}
`;

export const Overlay = styled.div`
background: #ff416c;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 0 0;
color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
left: -100%;
height: 100%;
width: 200%;
transform: translateX(0);
transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
${props => (props.signinIn !== true ? `transform: translateX(50%);` : null)}
`;

export const OverlayPanel = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
`;

export const LeftOverlayPanel = styled(OverlayPanel)`
  transform: translateX(-20%);
  ${props => props.signinIn !== true ? `transform: translateX(0);` : null}
`;

export const RightOverlayPanel = styled(OverlayPanel)`
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
    ${props => props.signinIn !== true ? `transform: translateX(20%);` : null}
`;

export const Paragraph = styled.p`
font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin: 20px 0 30px
`;
```

This is how I implement it on my Auth2.js (the reason for Auth2 is because I had created an Auth.js but I just want to use this new sign-in/up form which is very sick).

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal/AuthModal";
import * as Components from "./Components";

function Auth2() {
  const [signIn, toggle] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <Modal>
      <Components.Container>
        <Components.SignUpContainer signinIn={signIn}>
          <Components.Form>
            <Components.Title>Create Account</Components.Title>
            <Components.Input type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
            <Components.Input type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
            <Components.Input type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
            <Components.Input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Phone number"
              required
            />
            <Components.Input type="text" placeholder="Address" required />
            <Components.Button>Sign Up</Components.Button>
          </Components.Form>
        </Components.SignUpContainer>

        <Components.SignInContainer signinIn={signIn}>
          <Components.Form>
            <Components.Title>Sign in</Components.Title>
            <Components.Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <Components.Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <Components.Anchor href="#">
              Forgot your password?
            </Components.Anchor>
            <Components.Button>Sigin In</Components.Button>
          </Components.Form>
        </Components.SignInContainer>

        <Components.OverlayContainer signinIn={signIn}>
          <Components.Overlay signinIn={signIn}>
            <Components.LeftOverlayPanel signinIn={signIn}>
              <Components.Title>Welcome Back!</Components.Title>
              <Components.Paragraph>
                To keep connected with us please login with your personal info
              </Components.Paragraph>
              <Components.GhostButton onClick={() => toggle(true)}>
                Sign In
              </Components.GhostButton>
            </Components.LeftOverlayPanel>

            <Components.RightOverlayPanel signinIn={signIn}>
              <Components.Title>Hello, Friend!</Components.Title>
              <Components.Paragraph>
                Enter Your personal details and start journey with us
              </Components.Paragraph>
              <Components.GhostButton onClick={() => toggle(false)}>
                Sigin Up
              </Components.GhostButton>
            </Components.RightOverlayPanel>
          </Components.Overlay>
        </Components.OverlayContainer>
      </Components.Container>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default Auth2;
```

I passed it into a custom Modal.js reusable Component I made;

```
import { Fragment } from "react";


import classes from "./AuthModal.module.css";

const Backdrop = (props) => {
  return <div className={classes.backdrop} onClick={props.onClose} />;
};

const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      <div className={classes.content}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Modal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Backdrop onClose={props.onClose} />
      <ModalOverlay>{props.children}</ModalOverlay>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The AuthModal.module.css file

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;  
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 30;
  animation: slide-down 300ms ease-out forwards;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal {
    width: 40rem;
    left: calc(50% - 20rem);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-3rem);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

In the styled component, I tried using the display: flex but nothing happened. I also use inspector tool to see if I could manipulate all and sundry --- you guessed it - Nothing happened!

Please how do I make my sign in/out responsive? Please!

Comment: Can you share the Modal.module.css file?

Comment: I have edited my question to add it there. Thanks